# Insert week column in Excel

Tags: excel, date, weekday

I have a column in excel that has the day.

I want to add another column that will extract the week of that day (Mon-Sun) and display it as week ending on that Sunday's date.

```
     Day        
4/20/2019   
4/21/2019   
4/22/2019   
4/23/2019   
4/24/2019   
4/25/2019
```

Expected Output

```
      Day        Week
4/20/2019   4/21/2019
4/21/2019   4/21/2019
4/22/2019   4/28/2019
4/23/2019   4/28/2019
4/24/2019   4/28/2019
4/25/2019   4/28/2019
```

Does anyone know how to add this column using excel functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WEEKDAY` with the second parameter as 2 gives a number between 1 to 7 (7 being Sunday) for the day of the week. You can add to the date, the amount of days till that number becomes 7, in other words:

```
=A2+(7-WEEKDAY(A2,2))
```

[image]